# How to execute PHP code in Linux every 500 milliseconds?

Tags: scripts, cron, services

I have an http server on Linux.
I have some PHP code that stores variables into the cache using [memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.memcache.php) and I would like to execute this code every 500 milliseconds whenever the server is running, even after a server restart.
I was thinking of implementing a service but I don't have much experience with Linux so I don't know how to do this or if it is even the right approach.
I also heard of cron-jobs but I see that they run by the minutes and not by the seconds.
How can I execute PHP code in Linux every 500 milliseconds(Code would be helpful)?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: It seems logical to write a cli php script that will simply run and do it for you.  You could create a crontab to make sure it's running.  But you're right, crontab won't allow you to do sub minute jobs, unless you run multiples and stagger them, which at your time, IMHO is a bad idea.

Comment: Are you talking about milliseconds because you need *that* precision? Or do you just mean half a second?

Comment: I might need the millisecond precision in the future so its better to do it with milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple shell-script for that:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    php /path/to/your/script.php & sleep 0.5s;
done
```

The '&' will fork the process in the background, so the timing should be somehow accurate. I guess after some time it will become out of sync with a real clock, so you might either want to add timestamps to whatever your script does or use an approach with an daemon which uses the system time.

*(Thanks for the input in the comments)*

I recommend adding that script with systemctl. This tutorial looks fine for that:
[Creating my own systemd service files](https://kezhong.wordpress.com/2011/11/19/creating-my-own-systemd-service-files-on-fedora-16x86_64/)

Comment: Hm, they want to run it every 500 milliseconds, not every 500 seconds. Also the `php` job should be backgrounded, otherwise its execution time is added to `sleep`'s execution time.

Comment: thx, edited my answer.

in my manpage it said floating point is fine, but its mentioned, that other versions only accept integer values.

Comment: Still the `php` job should be backgrounded (`php /path/to/your/script.php &`). If the `php` job takes e.g. 0.25 seconds to run, `sleep`'s execution will be delayed by 0.25 seconds, and the script will run every 0.75 seconds instead of every 0.5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are familiar with PHP you can make a PHP daemon/service. I have made a PHP service for myself once because I had to use a library that was available only in PHP. It runs without any issue for many years now.

Here are some information about PHP daemons:

- https://github.com/shaneharter/PHP-Daemon
- http://kvz.io/blog/2009/01/09/create-daemons-in-php/
- http://collaboradev.com/2011/03/31/php-daemons-tutorial/
- http://stuporglue.org/writing-a-daemon-with-php/